# using jquery mobile with multiple headers per page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to show on my page 2 headers.
is it valid to use the following:

```html
<div data-role="page" class="<?php print $node_classes; ?>">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="inline"> 
        <h1><?php print $site_name; ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page-header ui-bar">
        <h2 class="ui-title"><?php print $title; ?></h2>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you define as "valid"

Will it render properly? I don't think so, better use:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="inline"> 
    <h1><?php print $site_name; ?></h1>
</div>
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="inline">
    <h2 class="ui-title"><?php print $title; ?></h2>
</div>
```

Does it make sense to do it? I don't think so, either